# Elastic Search Query using an OR operator inside a bool

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to build a simple query which translates to a condition as 
"age" is between 40 - 60 and "country" is US or IN . I am searching for a solution using a bool operator.

I tried with the below option:

```
    "bool": {
        "must": [
           {
               "range": {
                  "age": {
                     "from": 40,
                     "to": 60
                  }
               }
           },
           {
               "terms": {
                  "country": [
                     "US",
                     "IN"
                  ]
               }
            }
        ]
    }
```

But this query is not giving me any result. Am I missing something here?

Thanks! K

Comment: please post  the mapping of your  index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks fine. The only reason I think your query is not working is that the "coutry" field is using the default analyzer where the term is lower-cased and stored in the index. If you get expected results for the below query, my suspicion is correct. To fix it, either you can change your query to the one I've mentioned below or change your mapping to make the field "country" non-analyzed.

```
"bool": {
    "must": [
       {
           "range": {
              "age": {
                 "from": 40,
                 "to": 60
              }
           }
       },
       {
           "terms": {
              "country": [
                 "us",    <---- Note that I'm using lower-cased terms
                 "in"     <---- Note that I'm using lower-cased terms
              ]
           }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this works.. so does this mean the analyzer is used only for 'bool' condition? As the normal match query works with all case letters ( 'US', 'us', 'uS' )   for eg:     "query": {
        "match": {
           "country": "uS"
        }
    }

Comment: Good point. The difference is not between `bool` and `match` but between `terms` and `match`. While `match` query is designed to apply the same analyzer during searching as was applied during indexing, `term` or `terms` query does not. So `match` query will do the lowercasing for you before looking for the term in the index. `Terms` query will not do it and search for the word as is in index only to not find it. Hope I made sense.